# Set Woocommerce checkout field optional for a specific payment gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, checkout

I was setting up WooCommerce Checkout and I wanted to make the checkout fields optional for PayPal checkout as PayPal also require such data.

While I still want other gateways like Stripe to require checkout field being filled.

I am new to PHP. Here's the code I tried, but it didn't work:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' ,'custom_override_default_address_fields' );

 $answer = $_POST['payment_method'];

 if ( $answer == "cppec_paypal" ) {
    function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
        $address_fields['address_1']['required'] = false;
         return $address_fields;
    }
    ...
```

I want the field to be optional for PayPal, but required for Stripe.

The second option is that we somehow bring the paypal button from cart here as it didnt required the data but the checkout does

Thanks

Comment: you can use that if condition inside the function.

function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
if ( $answer == "cppec_paypal" ) {
        $address_fields['address_1']['required'] = false;
         return $address_fields;
}
    }

Comment: Thanks for the reply
i Tried that way, but all the fields in checkout disappeared 
and only phone, and email is left behind 
so it didnt worked properly but did made some change

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'optional_default_address_fields' );

function optional_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
$address_fields['company']['required'] = false;
$address_fields['postcode']['required'] = false;
$address_fields['city']['required'] = false;
$address_fields['state']['required'] = false;
return $address_fields;
}

please add all fields name which you want to make optional for paypal payment gateway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
i did like you asked but same result
https://imgur.com/a/7pDqTph
please take a look

Comment: so do you want to make that email also optional field ?

Comment: yes as we will get the email with paypal

Comment: i added this in the code, still the same result
  $address_fields['billing_email']['required'] = false;

Comment: $address_fields = apply_filters('woocommerce_billing_fields', $address_fields);
$address_fields = apply_filters('woocommerce_shipping_fields', $address_fields);

you can use these two filters to make email field optional.

Comment: still getting the same error

the paypal checkout button on product page and on checkout page doesnt require this data 

but the checkout page does

can we some how use the cart button here as well?

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: sorry but can't help you.